# How to modify a variable in a function with another function

Tags: python

I am trying to change `number` inside of `function` with `change_value` but as you can see it doesn't work

```
def change_value(number):

    number += 1


def function():

    number = 0

    change_value(number)

    print(number)


function()
```

When I run it, it prints out 0 instead of 1

Comment: You need to learn the difference between "pass by reference" and "pass by value". The short version is that `number` in your `change_value` function is a **different** variable than the one in your `function` function.

Comment: Read on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/937153

Comment: you should use `return number` in `change_value` and then you can do `number = change_value(number)`. This way everyone can see that you change value in variable `number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, all function parameters are [passed by object sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). This means you can mutate the value (if it is mutable), but you can never swap out a value for another (i.e. change the variable's binding, so that the original variable is affected).

Numbers are immutable. There is no way for you to do this.

If you place a number inside a mutable container (such as a list, a dict, or an object designed to do it), then you can do something like this:

```
def change_value(number_holder):
    number_holder[0] += 1

def function():
    number_holder = [0]
    change_value(number_holder)
    print(number_holder[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to achieve what you want

## Using a mutable

```
def change_value(number):
    number[0] += 1
def function():
    number = [0]
    change_value(number)
    print(number[0])
```

## Using classes

```
class myNumber:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.num = n

    def __add__(self, val):
        self.num += val

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.num)

def change_value(number):
    number += 1


def function():
    number = myNumber(0)
    change_value(number)
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects of built-in types like (int, float, bool, str, tuple, unicode) are immutable in python. So, what you can do here is to return the modified variable and reassign it.

**Code:**

```
def change_value(number):
    number += 1
    return number

def function():
    number = 0
    number = change_value(number)
    print(number)

function()
```

output:

```
1
```

Whereas, objects of built-in types like (list, set, dict) are mutable.

**code:**

```
def change_value(number):
    number.append(1)


def function():
    number = []
    change_value(number)
    print(number[0])

function()
```

output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed two lines in your code to get your desired result:-

```
def change_value(number):
    number += 1
    return number   # Returning an incremental value


def function():
    number = 0
    number = change_value(number)
    print(number)

function()
```

**Output**

```
1
```